# After Login unable to navigate between different View Controller showing only root ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a simple login-signup application using swift Xcode here I am able to successfully login-signup and navigate to MainViewController but unable to transition to other view controller when i pressed one of the button placed in MainViewController.I have set the root ViewController as MainViewController in AppDelegate file.
I tried setting nextView controller as root ViewController and pushed on navigation stack but i am unable to transition back to MainViewController and i don't think its a right solution..

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you are setting NextViewController as root view controller, you are removing MainViewController from the memory. So if you want to go back to MainViewController, you must push NextViewController on the same navigation controller as that of MainViewController.

Comment: Yes I removed setting nextViewControler as root view and pushed it on to the same navigation controller i.e Main View controller but I am not able to see any navigation Item which will navigate me back and also not able to see navigationItem title..

Comment: Created a segue way to navigate from Login View Controller to Main View Controller and i was able to navigate to other View Controller as the navigation items were visible.Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

Reffer to this link for switching between different application part:
https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-root-controller-navigation-3625eedbbff

Comment: I went through it does it mean that after Login we have to move our rootview Controller to Main ViewController in my case I have 2 navigation controller at the entry point for Login-SignUp and one at Main View controller after login..

Comment: You can have one navigation controller. After making the MainViewController as your RootViewController you can push other controller in the navigation stack. That stack will preserve all the reference of the pushed view controller along with the root view controller.